# fasten - for making something faster?

Tags: grammar

Is fasten a correct word to talk about something that would *fasten* a process i.e. make it faster. Example sentence :

> Warming up before running will fasten the metabolism.

Comment: We'd use the verb "speed" there.

Comment: @TimRomano - speed vs accelerate: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accelerate+the+metabolism%2C+speed+the+metabolism+&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccelerate%20the%20metabolism%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspeed%20the%20metabolism%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61: My sense is that you'd tend to find "accelerate" in scientific writing and "speed" in writing aimed at a lay audience.  *Warming up before running* suggests the latter context to me.

Comment: I have very rarely seen "fasten" used in the sense of "make faster" (I'm thinking in texts from the 1700s maybe).  I suspect this usage may have been technically correct at one time, but it's fallen into disuse for obvious reasons.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean [hasten](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hasten?s=t)?

Comment: @Josh61 It's **speed up** metabolism https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accelerate+the+metabolism%2Cspeed+up+metabolism&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccelerate%20the%20metabolism%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspeed%20up%20metabolism%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Mari-LouA - *accelerate* still cuts a nice figure compared to it.

Comment: @Josh61 Okay, "cuts a nice figure", is a very good expression :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fasten means a kind of firm attachment - check [this](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fasten) for reference.

To mean something which is happening fast, you can use [Quicken](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quicken).

Comment: I use Quicken for keeping my checkbook balanced.

Comment: 'Speed up' is a nice alternative to 'quicken'.

Answer (score 1):

To [fasten](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fasten) means:

> - to make or become fast or secure
> - to make or become attached or joined

To convey the idea of increasing the functions of metabolism ***[accelerate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/accelerate)*** is the term generally associated with it:

> - to increase the speed or velocity of; cause to move faster.

The Free Dictionary

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accelerate%20the%20metabolism&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccelerate%20the%20metabolism%3B%2Cc0) ***accelerate the metabolism***.

Etymology:

***Fasten*** derives from the original Old English meaning of fast ( firm, fix, secure), ***fast***  meaning quick appeared later, in the 16th century.

***[Fasten](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fasten)***:

> - Old English fæstnian "make fast, make firm, fix, secure," also "ratify, betroth, confirm," from Proto-Germanic fastinon "to make firm or fast", from PIE fast "solid, firm" ***(see fast (adj.)***.

***[Fast](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fast&allowed_in_frame=0):***

> - Old English fæst "firmly fixed, steadfast, constant; secure; enclosed, watertight; strong, fortified," probably from Proto-Germanic *fastu- "firm, fast"
> - Meaning "rapid, quick" is from 1550s.

Etymonline